# Can't get program executed with execv()

Tags: c, exec, gnuplot, execv

My code is:

```
char* arg_list[] = { "gnuplot", "gnuplot_script.sh", NULL };
printf("Ready %s %s\n", arg_list[0], arg_list[1]);
execv( "gnuplot", arg_list );
_exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

The output is:

```
Ready gnuplot gnuplot_script.sh
```

but nothing happens (while it should pop a graph).

I am copy-pasting the output, without "Ready " into the terminal, at the same place I just executed my program and it works. So I am not sure this is a path problem.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execv()` requires a path, e.g.:

```
execv("/usr/bin/gnuplot", arg_list);
```

You can use `execvp()` if you just want to supply a filename:

```
execvp("gnuplot", arg_list);
```

Both functions set `errno` on failure, so running `perror()` on failure will tell you what's going on.